# Using string with whitespace in the subprocess.call function in python

Tags: ssh, python, string, remote, whitespace

I am trying to use `ssh` command in the `subprocess.call` function of `Python 2.6.8` on Unix environment to call a remote script, and I need to provide a string parameter (with whitespaces) to the remote script. However, the string parameter is not being interpreted correctly when I run the python script.

Here is my python script :-

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 from subprocess import call

 ret=call(['ssh','user@host','\"/remote/path/to/script/test.sh','\'Hi','There\'\"'])

print ret

ret2=call(['ssh','user@host','/remote/path/to/script/test.sh','Hello'])

print ret2
```

I am getting following output with error and `returncode 127` for the ssh command with "whitespace string", and the second ssh command is running fine with `returncode 0` :-

```
bash: /remote/path/to/script/test.sh 'Hi There': No such file or directory

127

Hello

0
```

The same shell command executes successfully when I run it on shell command line terminal :-

```
Command:

ssh user@host "/remote/path/to/script/test.sh 'Hi There'";echo $?

Output:

Hi There

0
```

Here is the content of remote script `/remote/path/to/script/test.sh` (if it helps) :-

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo $1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to quote the string that is replacing the working version with `Hello`, namely `'"Hi There"'`:

```
ret = call(['ssh','user@host','/remote/path/to/script/test.sh','"Hi There"'])
```

Comment: It works.. I am so used to escaping special characters on shell script, that I did not even think about removing the backslashes.. Thanks!!